# Automatic Events Notification with Calendar?

Tags: email, notification, calendar

I am trying to achieve the following, according to a clients requirements:

Include Events happening around the year, each member should be notified automatically of the event before hand according to the time we set.

Is it possible to setup a calendar in which admin can add events and allow members to register for specific events and be notified automatically x number of days before the events ?

Can PostMaster Addon along with Low Events be used for such a setup ?

Is it possible to achieve the above with Native EE functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this with Native EE functionality.

With the Postmaster addon you can send [**"Post-dated"**](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/getting-started) emails (see step 4). It also offers a [**comprehensive API**](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/api/hooks) so you can build what you need if the default functionality won't do the trick.

Comment: Postmaster has all the postdated features built in, it's just a matter of how those add-ons handle events. Postmaster is definitely the best tool for the job (it was built for this), I just don't know if it's capable of doing everything they want without using the API (writing PHP).

Comment: ill look into Postmaster. So far thats the only solution which looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

How about a cron job?

There is a 1st party add-on here:
https://github.com/EllisLab/Cron-Email/blob/master/cron_email/pi.cron_email.php

Or commercial add-on:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/automatee

Though not sure how that would work with a specific date off the top of my head, but theoretically, can it not email a group of people by passing date variables into the parameters once an entry is created or something?

Answer (score 0):

The [**Scheduled trigger** *(free)*](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/scheduled-trigger) add-on allows you to trigger a hook when an entry rolls over the expiration_date (expires) or when it rolls into the entry_date (becomes active).

This way you can trigger a email via another add-on like **mx_notify** or **postmaster**.
Also the scheduled-trigger add-on is smart enough to update the schedule when you update the expiration or entry_date.